# Linq query with in clause and max

Tags: linq, max

I have a simple sql query but I cannot convert it to LINQ:

```
select * from client_software where update_date in 
    (select max(update_date) AS UPDATE_DATE from client_software a
        where a.client_code = client_software.client_code and
            a.software_code = client_software.software_code)
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Can you please give the answer a try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ans = from cs in client_software
          where cs.update_date == (from a in client_software where a.client_code == cs.client_code && a.software_code == cs.software_code select a).Max(cs2 => cs2.update_date)
          select cs;
```

Using a group by may be clearer in this case:

```
var ans2 = from cs in client_software
          group cs by new { cs.client_code, cs.software_code } into csg
          from cs in csg
          where cs.update_date == csg.Max(cs => cs.update_date)
          select cs;
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give this a try:

```
var q = entity.client_software.Where(r => r.update_date.Value
== entity.client_software.Where(u => u.client_code == r.client_code &&
u.software_code == r.software_code).Max(s => s.update_date)).ToList();
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks.